# Need help fixing gap between two divs in bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on the first project from FreeCodeCamp, and it's to make a tribute page to a notable individual. I am doing one on a female hockey player.

My problem is that I want her career acheivements section to be next to her biographical information, and line up with the sections above them.

```html
<style>
  .content-frame {
    background-color: #F34D57;
    border-style: double;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    border-width: 6px;
  }
  
  .imageborder {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
</style>
</head>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="biographical-info" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px" class="bio content-frame">
      <div class="col-xs">
        <b>Birthdate:</b> March 28, 1991
        <br>
        <b>Birthplace:</b> Beauceville, QC, CANADA
        <br>
        <b>Position:</b> Forward
        <br>
        <b>Playing Career:</b> 2007–present
        <br>
        <b>Shoots:</b> Left
        <br>
        <b>National Team:</b> Canada
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="career" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px" class="career content-frame">
      <div class="col-xs">
        <h3>
          <u>Notable Career Acheivements:</u>
        </h3>
        <p>
          <u>World Under-18 Championships:</u>
          <br>
          <b>Silver</b> (2008)
        </p>
        <p>
          <u>World Championships:</u>
          <br>
          <b>Gold</b> (2012), <b>Silver</b> (2009, 2011, 2013, 2015, 2016, 2017)
        </p>
        <p>
          <u>Winter Olympics:</u>
          <br>
          <b>Gold</b> (2010, 2014)
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's the codepen link: https://codepen.io/calvinkaing/pen/WXoPRY?editors=1100

Comment: in the codepen it's already next to the biography section. what the prooblem you are facing?

Comment: @IronyStack there is a gap, and it's not inline with the sections above it

Comment: It's not lining up vertically because those two sections are in a row, and the stuff above those is not in a row. For a basic site, I personally would recommend against Bootstrap and use CSS Grid for your basic layout and utility classes (I like [tachyons|http://tachyons.io/#getting-started]). These two things have helped me be able to create new mockups super fast since once you learn a few of the Tachyons classes, you don't have to keep looking up how to do things the bootstrap way and run into issues if you need to override something.

Comment: @CalvinNg check my answer and see if i helps, cheers if it does. if not inform me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap a column in a div, it should go `.row` then have `.col-xs` directly after that. Wrapping the columns in another div is what is messing it up. Move the outside div to the inside and it should make your content be side-by-side. From there if you want the vertical edges of the two boxes to be touching, you can remove the `padding-right` and `padding-left` of each box respectively.

Comment: Also, isn't padding for the contents of the div?

Comment: @CalvinNg it is for the contents of the div, but since you want them to look like they touch, you'd have to get rid of that spacing on one side, or instead put the red background on the `.col-xs` div.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the number of columns you want to use.
Bootstrap uses 12 columns grid system. So if u want the div's come next to eachother you need to set `<div class="col-xs-6">`

Answer (score 0):

I have just removed

```
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
```

and i hope it will work for you

```html
<style>
  .content-frame {
    background-color: #F34D57;
    border-style: double;
    text-align: center;
   
    padding-top: 5px;
    border-width: 6px;
  }
  
  .imageborder {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
</style>
</head>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="biographical-info" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px" class="bio content-frame">
      <div class="col-xs">
        <b>Birthdate:</b> March 28, 1991
        <br>
        <b>Birthplace:</b> Beauceville, QC, CANADA
        <br>
        <b>Position:</b> Forward
        <br>
        <b>Playing Career:</b> 2007–present
        <br>
        <b>Shoots:</b> Left
        <br>
        <b>National Team:</b> Canada
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="career" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px" class="career content-frame">
      <div class="col-xs">
        <h3>
          <u>Notable Career Acheivements:</u>
        </h3>
        <p>
          <u>World Under-18 Championships:</u>
          <br>
          <b>Silver</b> (2008)
        </p>
        <p>
          <u>World Championships:</u>
          <br>
          <b>Gold</b> (2012), <b>Silver</b> (2009, 2011, 2013, 2015, 2016, 2017)
        </p>
        <p>
          <u>Winter Olympics:</u>
          <br>
          <b>Gold</b> (2010, 2014)
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```